# LSTM error with date format

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, forex

This is my first attempt in deep learning, the purpose of this code is to predict the FOREX market direction.

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential

column_names = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low','Close', 'Volume']

data = pd.read_csv(r"E:\Tutorial\EURUSD60.csv", header=None, names=column_names)

data['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Date + ' ' + data.Time)
del data['Date']
del data['Time']

sequence_length = 21
n_features = len(data.columns)
val_ratio = 0.1
n_epochs = 300
batch_size = 512

data = data.as_matrix()
data_processed = []
for index in range(len(data) - sequence_length):
    data_processed.append(data[index: index + sequence_length])
data_processed = np.array(data_processed)

val_split = round((1 - val_ratio) * data_processed.shape[0])
train = data_processed[: int(val_split), :]
val = data_processed[int(val_split):, :]

print('Training data: {}'.format(train.shape))
print('Validation data: {}'.format(val.shape))

train_samples, train_nx, train_ny = train.shape
val_samples, val_nx, val_ny = val.shape

train = train.reshape((train_samples, train_nx * train_ny))
val = val.reshape((val_samples, val_nx * val_ny))

preprocessor = MinMaxScaler().fit(train)
train = preprocessor.transform(train)
val = preprocessor.transform(val)

train = train.reshape((train_samples, train_nx, train_ny))
val = val.reshape((val_samples, val_nx, val_ny))

X_train = train[:, : -1]
y_train = train[:, -1][:, -1]
X_val = val[:, : -1]
y_val = val[:, -1][:, -1]

X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], n_features))
X_val = np.reshape(X_val, (X_val.shape[0], X_val.shape[1], n_features))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:]), units=128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.add(Activation("linear"))

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")

history = model.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=n_epochs,
    verbose=2)

preds_val = model.predict(X_val)
diff = []
for i in range(len(y_val)):
    pred = preds_val[i][0]
    diff.append(y_val[i] - pred)

real_min = preprocessor.data_min_[104]
real_max = preprocessor.data_max_[104]
print(preprocessor.data_min_[104])
print(preprocessor.data_max_[104])

preds_real = preds_val * (real_max - real_min) + real_min
y_val_real = y_val * (real_max - real_min) + real_min

plt.plot(preds_real, label='Predictions')
plt.plot(y_val_real, label='Actual values')
plt.xlabel('test')
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()
```

Here is the error:

> Using TensorFlow backend. 2017-12-03 13:26:44.494199: W
>   C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but
>   these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU
>   computations. 2017-12-03 13:26:44.494660: W
>   C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but
>   these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU
>   computations. Training data: (1824, 21, 6) Validation data: (203, 21,
>   6) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:/Tutorial/Deep
>   Learning.py", line 42, in 
>       preprocessor = MinMaxScaler().fit(train)   File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py",
>   line 308, in fit
>       return self.partial_fit(X, y)   File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py",
>   line 334, in partial_fit
>       estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)   File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 433, in check_array
>       array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy) TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not
>   'Timestamp'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code after fixing the error

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential

column_names = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low','Close', 'Volume']

df = pd.read_csv(r"E:\Tutorial\EURUSD60.csv", header=None, names=column_names)

df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date + ' ' + df.Time)
del df['Date']
del df['Time']

df.rename(columns={'DateTime': 'timestamp', 'Open': 'open',
                   'High': 'high', 'Low': 'low', 'Close': 'close', 'Volume': 'volume'}, inplace=True)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
df = df.astype(float)
df['hour'] = df.index.hour
df['day'] = df.index.weekday
df['week'] = df.index.week


sequence_length = 21
n_features = len(df.columns)
val_ratio = 0.1
n_epochs = 300
batch_size = 512

data = df.as_matrix()
data_processed = []
for index in range(len(data) - sequence_length):
    data_processed.append(data[index: index + sequence_length])
data_processed = np.array(data_processed)

val_split = round((1 - val_ratio) * data_processed.shape[0])
train = data_processed[: int(val_split), :]
val = data_processed[int(val_split):, :]

print('Training data: {}'.format(train.shape))
print('Validation data: {}'.format(val.shape))

train_samples, train_nx, train_ny = train.shape
val_samples, val_nx, val_ny = val.shape

train = train.reshape((train_samples, train_nx * train_ny))
val = val.reshape((val_samples, val_nx * val_ny))

preprocessor = MinMaxScaler().fit(train)
train = preprocessor.transform(train)
val = preprocessor.transform(val)

train = train.reshape((train_samples, train_nx, train_ny))
val = val.reshape((val_samples, val_nx, val_ny))

X_train = train[:, : -1]
y_train = train[:, -1][:, -1]
X_val = val[:, : -1]
y_val = val[:, -1][:, -1]

X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], n_features))
X_val = np.reshape(X_val, (X_val.shape[0], X_val.shape[1], n_features))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:]), units=128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.add(Activation("linear"))

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")

history = model.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=n_epochs,
    verbose=2)

preds_val = model.predict(X_val)
diff = []
for i in range(len(y_val)):
    pred = preds_val[i][0]
    diff.append(y_val[i] - pred)

real_min = preprocessor.data_min_[104]
real_max = preprocessor.data_max_[104]
print(preprocessor.data_min_[:120])
print(preprocessor.data_max_[:120])

preds_real = preds_val * (real_max - real_min) + real_min
y_val_real = y_val * (real_max - real_min) + real_min

plt.plot(preds_real, label='Predictions')
plt.plot(y_val_real, label='Actual values')
plt.xlabel('test')
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a collision between expected **`dtype`**
and
tha actually delivered data type:

> `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'`

the most probable suspect to revise is the conversion in:

```
data['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Date + ' ' + data.Time)
```

You have to go back into the concept, what ( if at all ) ought be fed, as the set of the intended FOREX Quantitative Modeling Features, into the LSTM Model.